# Can a base runner steal during an appeal play?

Tags: rules, baseball, mlb

Can a player steal a base during an appeal play of another runner missing a bag?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Runners are allowed to advance at their own risk when the ball is in play (time out has not been called).

Different leagues have different rules about the specifics of the appeal process.  But for MLB, runner appeals are made when the ball is live, so a runner on base may attempt to steal during an appeal play.